# Como inserir um espaço em uma string de tamanho indefinido a cada 3 caracteres usando a linguagem R?

Tags: string, r

Tenho a seguinte string: "ADGALPASHA65CS7GWJMWHMWKRC3UPQXANXB9XMF0MH865" 
Preciso que seja inserido um espaço a cada 3 caracteres, de modo que ela fique assim: 
"ADG ALP ASH A65 CS7 GWJ MWH MWK RC3 UPQ XAN XB9 XMF 0MH 865"

```
my_string <- c("ADGALPASHA65CS7GWJMWHMWKRC3UPQXANXB9XMF0MH865")
string_with_spaces <- str_c(str_sub(my_string, start = 1, end = 3),
                                str_sub(my_string, start = 4, end = 6),
                                sep = " ")
```

Estou usando a função str_sub() porém não sei como escrever um algoritmo que faça a leitura total da strig até o último carácter até finalizar a inserção de todos os espaços a cada 3 caracteres.
Lembrando que, tenho várias strings para inserir estes espaços e elas não possuem o mesmo número de caracteres, mas sempre terminam separadas em blocos de 3 caracteres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar `gsub` para trocar grupos de 3 caracteres por 3 caracteres e um espaço:

```
gsub("(.{3})(?!$)", "\\1 ", my_string, perl = TRUE)
#> [1] "ADG ALP ASH A65 CS7 GWJ MWH MWK RC3 UPQ XAN XB9 XMF 0MH 865"
```

`(.{3})` indica um grupo formado por 3 caracteres quaisquer, que será substituído por esses três caracteres seguidos de um espaço (`\\1` ).

Para evitar que um espaço seja inserido no final, o `(?!$)` indica para desconsiderar a expressão anterior se ela estiver no final da *string*.

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro divida a string aplicando `gregexpr/regmatches` a uma regex. Depois junta.se tudo outra vez com `paste`.

```r
my_string <- c("ADGALPASHA65CS7GWJMWHMWKRC3UPQXANXB9XMF0MH865")
tmp <- regmatches(my_string, gregexpr(".{3}", my_string))[[1]]
paste(tmp, collapse = " ")
#> [1] "ADG ALP ASH A65 CS7 GWJ MWH MWK RC3 UPQ XAN XB9 XMF 0MH 865"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### Edição

Para modificar todos os elementos da coluna, é só generalizar o código acima. Não se escolhe só o primeiro membro da lista de `gregexpr` e aplica-se o `paste` a todos os elementos da lista num ciclo `sapply`.

```r
URL <- "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BW6F0vLzw3r7YsQ8lfQ6COZztoAsGoODLVj5_IIkr74/export?format=csv"
df1 <- read.csv(URL)

tmp <- with(df1, regmatches(my_string, gregexpr(".{3}", my_string)))
df1$string_with_spaces <- sapply(tmp, paste, collapse = " ")
df1
#>                                        my_string                                          string_with_spaces
#> 1     ADGALPASHAZ5A65GWJMWHMWKUPQXANXB9XMF0MH865     ADG ALP ASH AZ5 A65 GWJ MWH MWK UPQ XAN XB9 XMF 0MH 865
#> 2           ALPASHA65GWJMWHRC3UPQXANXB9XMF0MH865             ALP ASH A65 GWJ MWH RC3 UPQ XAN XB9 XMF 0MH 865
#> 3  ADGALPASHAZ5A65CS7GWJMWHMWKUPQXANXB9XMF0MH865 ADG ALP ASH AZ5 A65 CS7 GWJ MWH MWK UPQ XAN XB9 XMF 0MH 865
#> 4           ALPASHA65CS7GWJMWHUPQXANXB9XMF0MH865             ALP ASH A65 CS7 GWJ MWH UPQ XAN XB9 XMF 0MH 865
#> 5     AFBALPASHAZ5AZ6A65CS7GWJMWHUJXXANXB9XMF0MG     AFB ALP ASH AZ5 AZ6 A65 CS7 GWJ MWH UJX XAN XB9 XMF 0MG
#> 6                          AAUADBAPDLNCMDNXHQ0MH                                 AAU ADB APD LNC MDN XHQ 0MH
#> 7                             AAUADBLNCMDNXHQ0MH                                     AAU ADB LNC MDN XHQ 0MH
#> 8           AAVADBANTASHA77CLFLNCMY7UPQXAN0MH058             AAV ADB ANT ASH A77 CLF LNC MY7 UPQ XAN 0MH 058
#> 9        AAVADBANTASHA77CLFDSALNCMY7UPQXAN0MH058         AAV ADB ANT ASH A77 CLF DSA LNC MY7 UPQ XAN 0MH 058
#> 10                      ADBANTCLFDSAUPQXAN0MH058                             ADB ANT CLF DSA UPQ XAN 0MH 058
#> 11                      AAUADBAHUAPDLNCMDNXHQ0MH                             AAU ADB AHU APD LNC MDN XHQ 0MH
#> 12                         AAUADBAHULNCMDNXHQ0MH                                 AAU ADB AHU LNC MDN XHQ 0MH
#> 13                   ADBANTA76CLFMR5UPQXAN0MH058                         ADB ANT A76 CLF MR5 UPQ XAN 0MH 058
#> 14             ADBANTA76CLFDSALNCMR5UPQXAN0MH058                 ADB ANT A76 CLF DSA LNC MR5 UPQ XAN 0MH 058
#> 15                ADBANTCLFDSALNCMY7UPQXAN0MH058                     ADB ANT CLF DSA LNC MY7 UPQ XAN 0MH 058
#> 16 ADGALPASHA65CS7GWJMWHMWKRC3UPQXANXB9XMF0MH865 ADG ALP ASH A65 CS7 GWJ MWH MWK RC3 UPQ XAN XB9 XMF 0MH 865
#> 17          AAVADBANTA77CLFDSALNCMY7UPQXAN0MH058             AAV ADB ANT A77 CLF DSA LNC MY7 UPQ XAN 0MH 058
#> 18                   ADBANTCLFDSALNCUPQXAN0MH058                         ADB ANT CLF DSA LNC UPQ XAN 0MH 058
#> 19       ALPASHA65CS7GWJMWHMWKUPQXANXB9XMF0MH865         ALP ASH A65 CS7 GWJ MWH MWK UPQ XAN XB9 XMF 0MH 865
#> 20       ADGALPASHAZ5A65CS7GWJMWHMWKUPQXANXB9XMF         ADG ALP ASH AZ5 A65 CS7 GWJ MWH MWK UPQ XAN XB9 XMF
#> 21             ALPAZ6A65CS7GWJMWHXANXB9XMF0MG865                 ALP AZ6 A65 CS7 GWJ MWH XAN XB9 XMF 0MG 865
#> 22                ADBANTA76CLFDSAMRSUPQXAN0MH058                     ADB ANT A76 CLF DSA MRS UPQ XAN 0MH 058
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, porém acho que não me expressei corretamente. Na verdade, não tenho um vetor de strings e sim uma variável com várias estancias em um dataframe. Veja neste link um sub-set do arquivo original [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BW6F0vLzw3r7YsQ8lfQ6COZztoAsGoODLVj5_IIkr74/edit?usp=sharing] Se puder verificar agradeço!

Comment: @MaximilianoPrado A edição à resposta modifica todos os elementos da coluna, veja agora.